# Android play a video with controller

Tags: android, video, controls, playback

I'm using the following code to play a .mp4 video on my android device. I have 3 problems,

1. using this code when I press the back button on the device the sound would still continoue to play
2. It doesn't play the video, only plays the sound!
3. I don't know how to get controller for the video so the user can stop the video, go back or forth on the video.

   ```
   VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
   videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);    
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
   Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.video);

   videoHolder.setVideoURI(myUri);
   mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
   mediaPlayer.prepare();      
   mediaPlayer.start();

   videoHolder.requestFocus();
   videoHolder.start();
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Override onBackPressed in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mediaPlayer.stopPlayback();
    super.onBackPressed();        
}
```

2) Is it a valid video format? Are you using emulator or a real device? If you use an emulator, try a real device instead. I recall similar issues before.
But I also notice: did you put your video in the drawable folder?

```
R.drawable.video
```

I don't think that will work, you cannot play videos from there. Use the `resources/raw` folder instead. btw: Audio can be played from assets folder directly, while video cannot; video can only played from the raw folder or if you copy it to the apps files folder (`getFilesDir()`) - or sdcard of course.

3) Why are you using a VideoView AND a MediaPlayer, instead of just a VideoView? You should get rid of the mediaPlayer and just use the VideoView. This line

```
videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

looks correct and sets the media controller, with which the user can seek in the video.
Programatically you can also use `seekTo()` to go back and forth in a video.

Answer (score 0):

```
    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv01);

    //specify the location of media file
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.login_footage);

    //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
    videoView.setVideoURI(myUri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

This worked for me